Manifolds and covering maps
I am studying topological manifolds; I know that if $M$ is an $m$-topological manifold and $p:M\rightarrow N$ is a covering map, then $N$ is an $m$-manifold. I know how to prove the existence of local charts, but I am not able to prove that $N$ is Hausdorff and second countable: what I can say is that, since $p$ is a covering map, then $p$ is a local homeomorphism. Since $M$ is Hausdorff and second countable (so locally Hausdorff and locally second countable), then $N$ is locally Hausdorff and locally second countable.....but this does not imply that $N$ is Hausdorff and second countable too.
Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks for any help!

What you "know" is actually false. This was discussed many times on MSE.

Here's a counterexample.
